# "Name too long" error while creating webservice consumer in Domino Designer 8.5.2

Tags: java, web-services, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to consume a third party webservice in Lotus Notes. While creating consumer, I am getting "Name too long" error for few variables. I know, there is limit of 40 characters in creating variable in Lotus Notes. While I am trying to create Java consumer, its not getting created.

When I am creating consumer using lotusscript, "name too long" error for the declarations,

```
Const some42CharcaterlongName$ = "SomeTest"
Const some42CharcaterlongName$ = "SomeTest"
```

There are 20 such variables. I went through some articles and I found that consuming in java will solve this problem. I tried creating consumer in java, Notes will process for some time and then it will stop working. No error but no consumer created.

**Name too long error resolved -**

As @Emmanuel said, I just downloaded the wsdl locally and replaced the long names with shorter names and recreated the consumer and that's it...resolved.

**Running into another error - "Class or Type name not found"**

Any help on this?

Comment: Did you try make in your locally save wsdl a find&replace of this long const to something shorter? and re create the consumer importing the locally save wsdl ?

Comment: I am not sure how to edit wsdl locally. I tried to import the WSDL in webservice provider and changed the longer names with shorter names. When I am trying to save the file, "Operation Failed" error is appearing and not allowing to save.

Comment: Download the wsdl from the server (using your browser) save the xml on the wsdl on your drive. Then edit this file even with your xml editor or notpad if you haven't one.

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel. I just edited the wsdl. Name too long error now gone. But now I am running into another error "Class or type name not found". I believe making changes in the WSDL locally is not creating any problem. I need to check once with the provider. Please post your thought, if possible.

Comment: 1 - you must make replace the name (from long name to shorter one) in ALL occurence in the WSDL
2 - in case the WSDL import XSD, the same change must be done in also in the XSD. (this means downloading the XSD edit it in local + change the path in the WSDL)

Comment: Yes. I did that. I have replaced names at all xsd files. Which path I have to keep? Local or server?

Comment: the local wsdl need to link the local xsd, check that path in the import line on the wsdl is the one of your local xsd

Comment: Thank you for help. I have created provider using the WSDL URL and then the issue resolved. Do you know why "SSL bad peer certificate, Connection refused" error appears?

Comment: glad to have been for help. conserning the SSL, it could be http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/21382ebf75b2f57d852578db0077670a?OpenDocument... I suggest you to open a new question

Comment: Thanks again for all your help..I am working on SSL issue. It seems we need to add the cross certificate on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the wsdl on local. Edit it to make function names shorter. Mention that domino will concatenate the name and methods so you may have to shorten different "names".

Save locally
Recreate you consumer opening your edited version and it works.

I reread the question and sorry you mentionned java, so please read 
[Issues when importing WSDL files into Web Service Consumer](http://dpastov.blogspot.co.il/2014/09/issues-import-wsdl-files-domino-designer.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+dpastov+(Pastovenskyi+Dmytro)).

Comment: Will it not break the protocol of webservice provider?

Comment: One more thing, problem is not with function names. Variable names are too long. Do you have any reference to sort this thing out? I am really having bad time here with this issue :(

Comment: In the WSDL keep of course the <soap:address with location referencing the original server. Thus your consumer will communicate with the server even if the WSDL used to build it is local.

Comment: NB post here the precise error you get (if your problem is not solved).

Comment: Just added the error details in original post. Hope this will give you some idea.